# What are the required skills to bulid a online book editor?

Tags: web-development, javascript, html5, ruby-on-rails

I want to build a website for a printing company. My plan for this website is to offer a online book editor system for users to upload photos, choose the layout, type some text, put some stamp or sticker and so on.
Since I am only know about html and css, I would like to know what kind of person should I recruit.
Highly appreciated if anyone drops some suggestions.
The system is kind of like this, but more simple : http://www.lulu.com/blog/2008/08/21/lulu-studio-enhancements/